# need help regarding stored procedure in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table `tblEmployee` with columns `id, name, status`

Now I have to filter users by their status, where `0` stands for inactive users, `1` for active users, `2` for new users

Condition 1: I created a stored procedure like this:

```
IF (@Mode = 'ViewActive') 
BEGIN
SELECT * 
    FROM [tblEmployee] 
    WHERE Status = 1 
    ORDER BY DepartmentId, DOJ
END
```

This is to view active users

Condition 2:

Same way I want to create condition for active users & new users to display both at same time

I have tried

```
IF (@Mode='ViewActive') 
BEGIN
SELECT * 
    FROM [tblEmployee] 
    WHERE Status = 1, 2 
END
```

which shows an error.

Please help me to define second condition..  any new methods will be also helpful for me

Comment: What a terrible title. Please change it to be more descriptive of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
IF (@Mode='ViewActive') 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM [tblEmployee] WHERE Status in (1, 2 )
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Change that line to:

```
SELECT * FROM [tblEmployee] WHERE Status IN(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM [tblEmployee] WHERE Status IN (1, 2)
```